# How to setup Feathersjs with Nativescript

Tags: socket.io, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, feathersjs

I have made a simple backend with feathersjs for testing purposes.

For mobile application I am using nativescript with (angular 5). But one of the feathersjs client library require socketio-client.

socket.io-client library fails in nativescript.

So I used following nativescript plugins ( none of them works with featherSocketIOClient )

- nativescript-socket.io
- nativescript-socketio

Please help.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-socketio/issues/54)

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to use Feathers on the client to connect to a Feathers server.
[refer to the documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html)